# How do I customize Django Form ValidationErrors for built-in forms?

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm taking advantage of these built-in Django forms and I am running into a small issue.

- class AdminPasswordChangeForm
- class AuthenticationForm
- class PasswordChangeForm
- class PasswordResetForm
- class SetPasswordForm
- class UserChangeForm
- class UserCreationForm

For example, the `UserCreationForm` generates several validation errors which I can display in the my template using tags such as `{{ form.errors }}` or even ones related to a specific field such as `{{ form.username.errors }}`.

I know how to customize the styling of these error messages, but how can I customize the text? I have been able to simply check if an error exists with a conditional statement such as `{% if form.password.errors %}` and place my own custom text in that block. However, that leaves me blind to the type of error that was raised.

For instance, I want to be able to identify if the triggered error was a `duplicate_username` or a `password_mismatch` so I can write my own error in the template.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, you can customize the clean method like below:

```
class EventDetailsForm(form.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Event
        fields = ('name',)
        layout = (
                Fieldset('',
                'name',),
                )

    def clean_name(self):
        event_name = self.cleaned_data['name']
        if Event.objects.filter(name=event_name, status='Live').\
                exclude(id=self.instance.id).exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError('This Name is already in use')
        else:
            return event_name
```

So to re-use django's form, just subclass it, add additional validation logic and call that form in your view function.

Comment: Is that an ADDITIONAL check? Or does adding a clean method in a subclass of the original form override/replace the existing clean methods?

Comment: It will override it. So you can copy the existing validation methods and add in your own custom logic. Not super DRY but gets the job done.

Comment: Not sure if I'm misunderstanding things, but I just tried creating a subclass of `UserCreationForm` and `AuthenticationForm` and the original logic was still completely present. It would only change if I created functions with the same names to replace the original ones.

Comment: That is exactly the expected behaviour and what I meant. Som subclass the form, copy paste the clean method from django into your custom form. Add in the extra custom validation logic you require into that clean method.